# How to set onclick listener with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I'm trying to dynamically create a list images from a JSON array that will invoke a JavaScript function upon clicking one of the images. The function will send a request to the server, flagging that image. I currently have the following:

```
        var GLOBAL_POST_ID_LIST = [];
    function createList(jsonData) {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.posts.length; i++) {
            var curPostId = jsonData.posts[i].post_id;

            // Check if the current post is in the list
            if ($.inArray(curPostId, window.GLOBAL_POST_ID_LIST) < 0) {
                jQuery('<img/>', {
                    id: curPostId,
                    src: jsonData.posts[i].image_url,
                    selected: false,
                    onclick: onPostClick(curPostId)
                }).appendTo('#postDiv');
                // At the current post to the list
                window.GLOBAL_POST_ID_LIST.push(curPostId);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the onclick function is called immediately as the object is initialized, and not when the object is clicked on. How can I caused the onPostClick to be invoked with the correct post_id when any given post is initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a function:

```
onclick: function() { onPostClick(curPostId); }
```

Also, you need to get `curPostId` saved in a closure, otherwise you'll get the same value for all the elements (see [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)). So it should be:

```
onclick: (function(curPostId) {
            return function () { onPostClick(curPostId); };
         })(curPostId)
```

However, why do you need to pass the ID argument to `onPostClick` in the first place? jQuery automatically binds `this` to the event target in an event handler, so `onPostClick` should be able to use `this.id` to get the ID. If you fix the function to do that, you can just write:

```
onclick: onPostClick
```

You could also avoid this whole issue by giving your images a class and using event delegation. See [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
$("#yourId").click(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 3):

Invoke the function within an anonymous function:

```
  // Check if the current post is in the list
            if ($.inArray(curPostId, window.GLOBAL_POST_ID_LIST) < 0) {
                jQuery('<img/>', {
                    id: curPostId,
                    src: jsonData.posts[i].image_url,
                    selected: false,
                    onclick: function(){
                        onPostClick(curPostId);
                    }
                }).appendTo('#postDiv');
                // At the current post to the list
                window.GLOBAL_POST_ID_LIST.push(curPostId);
            }
```

This will prevent the `onclick` property from being assigned the result of invoking the `onPostClick` function.

Since you are binding this event handler within a loop you will need to create a closure to avoid getting stuck on the last value of the loop.

```
           jQuery('<img/>', {
                id: curPostId,
                src: jsonData.posts[i].image_url,
                selected: false,
                onclick: (function(id){
                    return function(){
                       onPostClick(id);
                    };
                })(curPostId)
            }).appendTo('#postDiv');
```